# How to assign a value to a column based on a column index

Tags: r

Having a data frame I would like to assign a calculated value based on a given a column index

```
df <- data.frame(a = c(2,4,7,3,5,3), b = c(8,3,8,2,6,1))

> df
   a b
 1 2 8     
 2 4 3
 3 7 8
 4 3 2
 5 5 6
 6 3 1

max <- apply(df, 1, which.max)
> max
[1] 2 1 2 1 2 1

addition <- apply(df, 1, sum)
> addition
[1] 10  7 15  5 11  4
```

Then some operation which I cannot figure out with the following result being assigned to df2

```
> df2
  a  b
1 2 10
2 7  3
3 7 15
4 5  2
5 5 11
6 4  1
```

highly appreciate your ideas and your help. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can also use vectorised `ifelse` directly:

```
with(df, cbind.data.frame(a = ifelse(a > b, a + b, a), b = ifelse(a > b, b, a + b)));
#  a  b
#1 2 10
#2 7  3
#3 7 15
#4 5  2
#5 5 11
#6 4  1
```

Comment: Thank you! That works. If was trying to avoid `ifelse`statements, since having the positions I feel it more elegant. But nonetheless that works too, and I think it is clearer for a reader.

Comment: @JeanPaul No worries, glad to help. Keep in mind that `ifelse` is vectorised, so it'd be interesting to run a benchmark comparison with the `cbind` method to see which method is faster.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `cbind` to access your selected columns for each row:

```
df2 = df
df2[cbind(1:nrow(df2),max)] = addition
df2
  a  b
1 2 10
2 7  3
3 7 15
4 5  2
5 5 11
6 4  1
```

Here, `cbind` returns a matrix of 2 columns and 6 rows that we use to subset the dataframe using matrix subsetting.

Comment: You can do it without the `apply` calls with `max.col` and `rowSums`: `df[cbind(seq(nrow(df)), max.col(df))] <- rowSums(df)`

Comment: Thank you very much! I as missing the `cbind()` at the left hand side. I was trying  `df[,max] <- addition`. Could kindly explain why this throws an error, but including the `cbind` and the row index generated by `seq` works?

Comment: Well using `df[,c(2,1,2,1,2,1)]` for example would select the entire 2nd column, 1st column, 2nd column, 1st column etc resulting in a dataframe with 6 columns and 6 rows. That's why you get an error when trying to assign it the addition vector. Here, `cbind()` returns a `matrix`, which we use to subset the dataframe.